# Use series methods to find solution corresponding to..

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Use series methods to find solution corresponding to $a_0 = 1$ for the equation $(x+1)y' - y = 0$

Here is my work. Can someone verify that I have the correct solution:
[image]

So for my final solution I have

recursive formula: $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n(1-n)}{n+1}$

$y_1 = 1 + 0.. + 0 .. + ...$

so $y = C_1y_1$

Comment: Anyone? I'm not sure how to check my answer

Comment: You check your answer by plugging it in.  Clearly you must have made a mistake because $y=C_1y_1 = C_1$ is not a solution to $(x+1)y'-y=0$ (because $0-C_1 =0 \implies C_1=0$ is too boring to call a solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive formula should be $$a_{n+1} = \frac {1-n}{n+1}a_n$$ You just made a small sign error.  Then just plug in $a_0=1$ and find the next few values by hand.

$$a_0 = 1 \implies a_1=1 \implies a_2 =0$$  Then we don't need to go any further because we can see by our recursive formula that every $a_n$ for $n\ge 2$ must equal $0$ as well.  So your solution is just $y=1+x$.  And it's easy to check that this solution works.

Comment: could you check this one as well? http://mathhelpboards.com/differential-equations-17/use-series-methods-solve-2-a-15110.html#post71130

Comment: You're saying $y_1 = 1+x$ but do you mean $y_1 = 1 + 0 + 0 ...$ There shouldn't be a x right?  We are told in the beginning that $a_1 = 0$ (notice in beginning of problem) or am i wrong

Comment: I see $a_0 = 1$.  I don't see $a_1=0$ anywhere.  And if you *did* have $a_1=0$, the only solution would be the trivial solution.

Comment: ah i see what you're saying

Comment: so it would be $y_1 = 1 + x + ... + ...$

Comment: If all of those $\dots$ are supposed to be zeros, then yes.  If they're supposed to mean $+x^2 + x^3+\cdots$, then no.

Comment: no , they definitely mean $0s$ as you have said. You are correct i made a mistake via the recursive formula. I now see that every n $\ge$ 2 is going to give us $0$

Comment: Also do I need to put it in the form $y = C_1y_1 $?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, but not being in your class, IDK.  You should ask your professor/ TA.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Thanks @Bye_World. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: could I get you to check this out if you get a chance? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253729/use-series-methods-to-solve