# Eigenvectors of the matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm getting frustrated with a question. I'm trying to find the eigenvector of $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1/2 & 0 \\ 0& 2\end{array} \right)$ and it's been a few good years since I've had to touch eigenvectors.

I get the characteristic polynomial is $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1/2-\lambda & 0 \\ 0& 2-\lambda \end{array} \right)$, and solving this gives me $2$ eigenvalues of $\lambda = 1/2$ and $\lambda = 2$.

Solving for $\lambda = 1/2$, I get the matrix $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0& 3/2\end{array} \right)$

When solving the above matrix, I get a system of equations:

$$\left\lbrace\begin{array}{l}  0x + 0y = 0
\\  0x + 3/2y = 0 \end{array} \right.$$

And thus solving this yields me $x = 0$, and $y = 0$ which is incorrect. The correct answer is $(1,0)$ for $\lambda = 1/2$.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you get $x=0$ out of the equations $\begin{cases} 0=0 \\ (3/2)y=0\end{cases}$?

Comment: I assumed the first equation in the system of equations meant 0x + 0y = 0. I may be wrong here.

Comment: $0x+0y=0$ is the same as $0=0$. I was just too lazy to write out the unnecessary terms.

Comment: So I just picked some numbers that satisfied the equation, x = 0 and y = 0 do the job, as do x = -1, and y = 800.

Comment: $(0,0)$ *always* does the job so we actually rule that out as an eigenvector.  $(-1,800)$ does *NOT* do the job.  Try plugging this in to the equation $\pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ 0 & (3/2)}\pmatrix{x \\ y}=\pmatrix{0 \\ 0}$.  Does it work?

Comment: Sorry I meant (-1, 800) satisfies 0x + 0y = 0, but like you said that would always do the job so my misunderstanding was there. I should have checked to see if it worked for the second equation though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{cases} 0x+0y=0 \\ 0x+\frac 32y=0\end{cases} \iff \begin{cases} 0=0 \\ \frac 32y=0\end{cases}$$

That first equation doesn't give us any information.  It's simply a tautology (something of the form $a=a$).  Solving the second equation however, we see that $y=0$. But you can see that there aren't any conditions on the value of $x$.  So the solutions to this matrix equation are $$\pmatrix{x \\ y} = \pmatrix{t \\ 0}$$ for *any* arbitrary real number $t$.  But while there are an infinite number of solutions, they're all just scalar multiples of each other so we generally just choose one of them and call it "the" eigenvector.  A good choice might be $t=1$, but you can choose any other value you like.  Then you'll get your eigenvector $\pmatrix {1 \\ 0}$.

Comment: can you check one of my diferential problems and see if I've done it correctly? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253490/use-series-methods-to-find-solution-corresponding-to

Comment: That makes sense, thanks alot. (0,0) cannot be an eigenvector right?

Comment: No.  $0$ is the one value of $t$ you *can't* choose because we define eigenvectors so that they're not the zero vector.

Comment: Okay, thanks alot for answering my question, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The condition
$$
\frac{3}{2}y=0
$$
gives $y=0$. However, there are no more conditions and so $x$ may take any real value.

Comment: That's what I was thinking was done but I wasn't 100% sure, thanks alot for this, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the diagonal matrix $$A = \pmatrix{1/2&0\\0&2}? $$ we have $$Ae_1 = \frac 1 2 e_1, Ae_2 = 2e_2 \text{ where } e_1 \ \pmatrix{1\\0}, e_2=\pmatrix{0\\1}.\tag 2$$ the equation already tells you that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1/2, 2.$

Comment: How does one go on to find the eigenvectors from these eigenvalues?

Comment: @Ftahir192, for a diagonal matrix, the eigenvalues are on the diagonal and the corresponding eigenvectors are the columns of the identity matrix. you need to work a lot more if the matrix is not diagonal. the whole point of eigenvectors is that a matrix is essential diagonal if we choose the eigenvectors as a basis.

Comment: Ah, okay, I didn't know that. I knew how to work it out for non-diagonal matrices but not for diagonal matrices. I thought it would follow a similar procedure. Thanks for the info, that'll be useful :)